# I'm having a problem with using pointers for strings

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
char slova(char a);
int main()
{
    char a[100];
    fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
    char slova(a);
    return 0;
}
char slova(char a)
{
    int i,x=0,y=0,n;
    n=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
        if(*(a+i)>='A' && *(a+i)<='Z') x++;
        if(*(a+i)>='a' && *(a+i)<='z') y++;
    }
    if(y>x) return -1;
    if(y<x) return 1;
    if(x==y || (x==0 && y==0)) return 0;
    
}
```

The task is to return -1 in case the string has more lowercase letters, to return 1 if it has more uppercase and to return 0 if it has 0 letters or equal number of uppercase and lowercase. I'm dealing with this type of a task for the first time and I have loads of mistakes and not sure how to fix them. Here are the errors.

```
11  14  C:\Users\x\Documents\asgsgg.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
17  12  C:\Users\x\Documents\asgsgg.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
20  11  C:\Users\x\Documents\asgsgg.cpp [Error] invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

The last one appears 2 times in line 20 and 2 times in line 21.

Comment: You're never calling `slova`. `char slova(a);` is a function declaration, not a function call.

Comment: `char a` declares a single character, not a pointer to a string.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of the function.

Comment: `char slov(a);` declares a character, which is where the first error comes from.

Comment: You include `<math.h>` but use nothing from it; don't include it.  You include `<ctype.h>` but use nothing from it; use `isupper()` and `islower()`.  Your function `slova()` doesn't always return a value —  that's bad if the value is used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is it bad if i included them but didnt use them? Could that cause problems in the future tasks? And also im not quite sure what do you mean with it doesnt always return a value.

Comment: Your filename suffix is `.cpp`. That's usually used for C++, not C. What language are you actually programming?

Comment: At one k OK even, including unused headers is harmless; it should not cause the compilation to fail.  At another level, it is wasteful and misleading.  It causes the compiler to read unnecessary files and store irrelevant information, which makes compilation a little slower.  It also leads programmers looking at your code to wonder why the headers are included when the facilities provider by the header aren't used.  There are many worse coding problems.  It's still a good idea to keep things minimal — it's easier to understand the code if there's no irrelevant information to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `slova()` function, not just declare it, and do something with the result, e.g. print the result.

The argument should be `char *a`, not `char a`, so it's a pointer to the string, not a single character.

You should use the functions `isupper()` and `islower()` rather than checking the character ranges yourself.

There's no need to check for `(x==0 && y==0)`; if they're both `0` then `x == y` will be true. You can also use a series of `else if` followed by `else` at the end.

You have an extra `;` at the end of the `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` line, so the code block after it is not in the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int slova(char *a);
int main(void)
{
    char a[100];
    fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
    printf("Result: %d\n", slova(a));
    return 0;
}

int slova(char *a)
{
    int i,x=0,y=0,n;
    n=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(isupper(*(a+i))) x++;
        if(islower(*(a+i))) y++;
    }
    if(y>x) return -1;
    else if(y<x) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: It always prints out 0 whatever i enter.

Comment: You had an extra `;` at the end of the `for` line, so the loop was empty.

Comment: All fixed didnt notice the extra ; thank you very much

Comment: Always enable full warnings. My compiler warned "for loop has empty body"

Comment: How do i enable that?

Comment: check the documentation of your compiler or IDE. It's enabled by default on my Mac.